Concrete foundation spalling
My home is about 55 years old with a poured concrete foundation. I’ve noticed some spalling and efflorescence appearing in some areas with moisture, no standing or running water leaks, no visible cracks in the foundation.
I was thinking of having a foundation specialist come out and take a look just to be on the safe side, but they all seem to specialize in slightly different things. Should I call someone who specializes in waterproofing? Who should I call who can make an honest informed assessment.
Thanks for the advice!

It depends what problem you're trying to solve. I guess it's not a finished basement. The most dire issue is that of frost heave, that is that the ground outside of your basement becomes frozen, expands, and cracks the foundation. Since this foundation is 55 years old and uncracked this doesn't seem to be much of a problem. You might start with just landscaping and gutters to make sure all the water is shed away effectively. Waterproofers deal with excavating around the foundation, placing French drains, and insulating the basement. The price tag for that work is astounding.

Thanks, I put gutter extenders on and have gutter guards installed. That didnt seem to help. It’s like the concrete wall is sweating when it’s humid or had a day of steady rain.

Concrete walls indeed do sweat, but pay close attention to the difference between humid air and wet soil. Water travels through dirt, and concrete, and eventually you get hydrostatic pressure and the spalling. To my knowledge spalling isn't bad in its own right. Lots of homeowners just clean it off occasionally. I don't even bother with that.

There are things you can do by yourself, like making sure the gutters are working and taking water away from the foundation. For example, if the gutters are discharging right on the foundation, buy extenders and make sure the water goes away from the house. If the house is on a hill, you should make sure the water coming down the hill is diverted away from the house.
But assuming that you've taken care of the obvious stuff, usually work like this is done by landscape contractors. They might recommend a French Drain around the perimeter with a sock pipe draining into a dry well. Or removing the lawn and re-grading the yard so that the surface leans away from the house.
Just make sure to get several quotes. Drainage work around houses is more art than science, and when judging possible solutions, experience matters the most.
